# System global, portable locks in Python - how?

Tags: python, windows, locking, posix

I'd like to do something like this:

```
lock = GlobalSemaphore("my-sytem-global-name")

try:
    lock.acquire()
    # Do my stuff here
finally:
    lock.release()
```

The global name can be in the filesystem namespace, or some other namespace, it doesn't really matter.  There is asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(), which can be used for asyncio.  There's a semaphore for threading.  There's also a semaphore hidden in the multiprocessing module, which I'm assuming can sync across a pool of processes.  It seems a glaring omission to not give general access to these classes for arbitrary processes, so I wondered if I've missed something.

Comment: With arbitrary processes, you mean also those not using Python? Anyway, you may use ```os.lockf``` and ```msvcrt.locking``` but you have to switch implementations based on the OS, I guess because of different semantics

Comment: No, this is only for Python.  I've not used msvcrt and instead used win32 extensions to access a global mutex in the past.

Comment: If everything happens in Python, you can use a multiprocessing.Manager to provide the semaphore. Note the address argument and connect method. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers

Comment: @Homer512 I would appreciate example code if you're able to put that in an answer.